# How do I decode an image url Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, web, decoding

I have an image URL that has been encoded to escape the slashes.

```
https:\\/\\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\\/adido-toolbank\\/Thumbnails\\/F\\/FLV26461.JPG
```

How do I go about decoding this URL in jquery?
decodeURI and decodeURIComponent are not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` and `join()`. Do this:

```js
var url = "https:\\/\\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\\/adido-toolbank\\/Thumbnails\\/F\\/FLV26461.JPG";

console.log( url.split( String.fromCharCode(92) ).join('') );
```